# Is it acceptable to have dangling participle a century ago? and what's the implication of a literally understandable sentence?

Tags: implication, dangling-participle

> **Being wise**, their gifts were no doubt wise ones, **possibly bearing the privilege of exchange in case of duplication.** (From The Gift of The Magi by O. Henry)

Clearly "being wise" here is a dangling participle. Since it was written more than a century back, is this an acceptable use? Or it's just a mistake?

Also I don't understand the implication of the bold text at the end, though knowing the literal meaning of it.

Comment: The meaning is clear enough, though it is technically a dangling participle. I'm not aware that this was any more correct a century ago. The phrase at the end is a mildly humorous way of suggesting that the recipient had the option to exchange one of the gifts for something else if he received two the same.

Comment: It's worth noting the two sentences that precede the quote, sentences that make it perfectly clear who are being referred to in the participle that follows: **The magi, as you know, were wise men - wonderfully wise men - who brought gifts to the Babe in the manger. They invented the art of giving Christmas presents.**

Comment: Competent writers (such as O Henry) don't care about "schoolboy grammar sins" such as dangling participles. The cited text is a perfectly acceptable example of a competent writer plying his trade - it just *wouldn't* be "acceptable" if he were a student hoping to pass an exam!